# Unable to get request from onelogin app to my SCIM server

Tags: onelogin, scim, scim2

I am trying to build onelogin SCIM Provisioner with SAML (Core Schema) app for my scim server. I have done all configurations related to it, but still I am not able to get any request to my server.

My base url is `mydomain.org/scim/v2` which handles all scim routes that is `/users` or `/groups` So final route will be something like `mydomain.org/scim/v2/users` and `mydomain.org/scim/v2/groups`.

I have provided a bearer token for authorization, What else do I need to configure?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, it's that by default you application is setup to require admin approval on user creation or provisioning isn't enabled for you application.

You should check that provisioning is turnd on and admin approval is off on the provisioning tab for your application or go to the users tab on your application and see if there are users waiting to be approved by an admin.

Comment: I contacted onelogin support and they say its because of the following error observed:
 **EXCEPTION: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: tlsv1 alert internal error**